# Crystal Reports with SQLite database

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, crystal-reports

Can we work with Crystal Reports in Visual Studio with a SQLite database?

Comment: Just a friendly warning, you should look at your previous questions and, where applicable, accept some answers. You can do that by checking the checkmark next to the answer of your choice. Look up the FAQ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the question is just that, yes, it can work.

EDIT:

- [Introduction to Crystal Reports in .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/crystalreportsintroduction11082005014959am/crystalreportsintroduction.aspx)
- [System.Data.SQLite, ADO.NET provider for SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Comment: See edit. They are good ressources, but you need to do some reading.

Comment: are you sure it is an answer to my question ?! it wasn't useful !

Comment: I'm not going to write your program for you. You asked if Crystal Reports can work with SQLite, I said yes. You asked how, I said read. Read up on Crystal Reports and you will see how you can put data in the report. It says it right there in 10 easy steps.

Comment: my dear friend, i mean i couldn't find a way to make relation between SQLite & Crystal ! and also i've done many of google searches,and im really confused !!! sorry ! plz help me...

Comment: my problem is there is no part in wizard of crystal report to define database for SQLite DB !

Comment: i really want to know if it is possible to work SQLite with Crystal Report or not,if yes then how ? thank you . i don't have enough time for reading hundred of pages , sorry ! i need simple & complete solution . in final i thank from every body !

Comment: Look, what I'd do try to setup an ADO.NET connection with the ADO.NET provider for SQLite, then do the Crystal Reports tutorial. I don't personnally use Crystal Reports. I know it's not a magical tool, I know it can be fed with any ADO.NET enabled database. If you don't want to read, I'm not doing your work for you.

Comment: ok, except crystal,are there some softwares to make report from SQLite DB ? i also tried Stimul but not affect ! i have done a big project in C# with SQLite DB and i have to make reports from DB,but i can't & im really confused !!! plz help me ...