# connecting sqlite database with crystal report in Visual Studio-2012

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite, crystal-reports-2010

In Visual Studio 2012 Server Explorer the sqlite tables are connected and visible but in Field Explorer I don't know which data provider is suited for sqlite database ? Tell me How to Connect field Explorer of crystal report to sqilte Database? Thanks

Comment: This answer dont helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014337/crystal-reports-with-sqlite-database

Comment: You can see my question with image on following link :http://www.dbtalks.com/Forums/Thread/1400/connecting-sqlite-database-with-crystal-report-in-vs-2012.aspx